# how to run on .xls file from A7 and make .csv file?

Tags: c#

i need to run on excell (.xls) file from A7 cell

(because he has a picture in the cell A1)

and make a .csv file

how to do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

General overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7(VS.80).aspx

Specific Tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syyd7czh(v=VS.80).aspx

Reading/Writing to a cell: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ad4d8d6(v=VS.80).aspx